# SQL Server: grouping continuous value of a column

Tags: sql-server, performance, common-table-expression

I have this view `vMobileHistory_MobileRegion` which is like:

```
strUnitID       strDate     strTime   iMobileHistory   isValidRegion
---------------------------------------------------------------
352848028160311 1394/11/01  10:35:16    33029937      0
352848028160311 1394/11/01  10:35:17    33029938      0
352848028160311 1394/11/01  10:35:18    33029939      1
352848028160311 1394/11/01  10:35:19    33029940      1
352848028160311 1394/11/01  10:35:20    33029941      1
352848028160311 1394/11/01  10:35:22    33029942      0
352848028160311 1394/11/01  10:35:25    33029943      0
352848028160311 1394/11/01  10:35:28    33029944      0
352848028160311 1394/11/01  10:35:34    33029945      1
352848028160311 1394/11/01  10:35:35    33029946      1
```

Indexes are:

```
ClusterdIndex, strUnitID ASC, strDate DESC, strTime DESC
NonClusterdIndex, iMobileHistory ASC
NonClusterdIndex, strDate ASC, strTime ASC
NonClusterdIndex, strUnitID ASC, strDate ASC
```

I have this query that is to Group rows based continuous values "isValidRegion"

```
SELECT
    strUnitID,
    strDate,
    strTime,
    isValidRegion,
    iMobileHistory,
    (ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY strUnitId ORDER BY strDate, strTime)
     - 
     ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY strUnitId, isValidRegion ORDER BY strDate, strTime)
    ) AS grp
FROM 
    vMobileHistory_MobileRegion 
GROUP BY
    strUnitID, strDate, isValidRegion, grp
```

The problem is that `vMobileHistory_MobileRegion` has over 100M of rows and using `ROW_NUMBER()` on it causes calculating `ROW_NUMBER()` for all rows which is really slow and causes sorting data in `tempdb` because of large data that does not fit in the memory.

Is there any other way without using `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Actually, I need time duration for each continuous value of isValidRegion

Comment: What are you trying to calculate with the row_number function?

Comment: This is to calculate difference of RowNumber for  two different partitioning to know if "isValidRegion" is continuous or not

Comment: Do you have any index(es)? It's not `ROW_NUMBER()` causing main performance problems, sorting 100M records is slow.

Comment: Actually, I need time duration for each continuous value of isValidRegion

Comment: Paweł Dyl: 
Yes I have indexes, problem is that sorting 100M record causes oprator to spill data to tempdb which is really slow.

I can post Actual execution plan if its gonna help

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :) I was supposed to write: can you share index definitions with us? Moreover, why date is separated from time? Those are strings? (I am curious of str prefix).

Comment: Yes these are Strings because of localization issues with date-time (this is because db server is not connected to Internet and its time and time-zone are going wrong occasionally). vMobileHistory_MobileRegion  is getting data from three different tables. Indexes are:

 --- ClusteredIndex, strUnitID ASC, strDate DESC, strTime DESC ----
NonClusteredIndex, strUnitID ASC, iMobileHistory ASC ----- 
NonClusterd, index_dateTime, strDate ASC, strTime ASC ----

Comment: Instead of row number, you could use lag() to check when the value changes, and then show 1, else 0 and do a running total over that. That way I would assume only 1 sorting is needed. That might be little better than 2 row numbers.

Comment: I've tired using lag(), performance is awesome, but unfortunately I could not get time duration for each continuous group. That would be great if you tell me how to do that, I mean seleting min(strtime) and max(strTime) for each continuous group of isValidRegion

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully reproduce your environment, but here is what I did (conceptually):

```
CREATE TABLE Regions
(
    UnitID char(15),
    EventTime datetime2,
    MobileHistory int,
    IsValidRegion bit
)

--Notice EventTime is not DESC, compacted to one column
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_MobileHistory ON Regions(UnitId, EventTime)

--You can join columns strDate and strTime in CTE expression
--I omited this for simiplicity
TRUNCATE TABLE Regions
INSERT Regions VALUES
('352848028160311', '1394/11/01 10:35:16', 33029937, 0),
('352848028160311', '1394/11/01 10:35:17', 33029938, 0),
('352848028160311', '1394/11/01 10:35:18', 33029939, 1),
('352848028160311', '1394/11/01 10:35:19', 33029940, 1),
('352848028160311', '1394/11/01 10:35:20', 33029941, 1),
('352848028160311', '1394/11/01 10:35:22', 33029942, 0),
('352848028160311', '1394/11/01 10:35:25', 33029943, 0),
('352848028160311', '1394/11/01 10:35:28', 33029944, 0),
('352848028160311', '1394/11/01 10:35:34', 33029945, 1),
('352848028160311', '1394/11/01 10:35:35', 33029946, 1)
```

Here is the final query, splitted to CTEs to see parts of solution:

```
WITH Lagged AS
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN LAG(IsValidRegion) OVER (PARTITION BY UnitId ORDER BY EventTime) <> IsValidRegion THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsChange,
        ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second, EventTime, LEAD(EventTime) OVER (PARTITION BY UnitId ORDER BY EventTime)), 0) TimeSpan,
        IsValidRegion*1 IsValidRegion, MobileHistory, UnitId, EventTime
    FROM Regions
),
LaggedGroupChanges AS
(
    SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN IsChange=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY UnitId ORDER BY EventTime) ChangeGroup
    FROM Lagged
)
SELECT UnitId, SUM(TimeSpan) TotalTime,
    MAX(IsValidRegion) IsValidRegion,
    MIN(MobileHistory) MinMobileHistory,
    MAX(MobileHistory) MaxMobileHistory
FROM LaggedGroupChanges
GROUP BY UnitId, ChangeGroup
```

It requires only one sort operation caused by final GROUP BY. The results below:

```
UnitIdTotalTime TotalTime IsValidRegion MinMobileHistory MaxMobileHistory
352848028160311 2         0             33029937         33029938
352848028160311 4         1             33029939         33029941
352848028160311 12        0             33029942         33029944
352848028160311 1         1             33029945         33029946
```

If there is no end time specified, I used 0. TotalTime is in seconds, your query may be tweaked to use some different methods to calculate time spans due to strDate and strTime columns.

Comment: This is perfect Pawel, I really liked this way of thinking, but this is taking about  40 sec to return result too (same as my query). I;m using this  query mostly for an specific date ( where strDate = XXXX ). this is taking about 40s to return result. But if i filter more, like (where strDate = XXX and strTIme > '12:00') this will be take less than 1 seconds!

and the only difference to execution plan is that sorts are not spilled to tempdb any more, maybe I have to do something about server memory

Comment: How many sort operations are in yours/mine execution plan? Is it only 1? How large is that table vs server memory?

Comment: Your has 1 sort and this is perfect (my query has 2 sorts). But I think these sorts are already done because of indexes. I will post actual execution plan of your query and mine.